# Second object won't animate with first one

Tags: objects, rigify

Hi i'm having this problem when i try to change bone position with rigify (there's similar problem even with normal bones) :
[image]

As you can see the cloak doesn't move like the rest of the body . The cloak and the hood (the hood has this problem as well but it's not visible here) used to be different objects but i joined them with Ctrl + J .

What i've tried and didn't work : "playing" in weight paint , merge cloak points and body points with Alt + M .

Notes : Don't mind the eyes(didn't parent them yet) . Sorry for the bad quality and the speed of this gif but i think we can't upload a video here so i had to convert it to gif . I still have the backup .blend file where i haven't joined the objects yet .

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Okay first of all, a common rule for character rigging is that you don't need to have any skin that is covered by character clothing, therefore go ahead and delete those skin. But of course you can choose to keep those skin if you feel like you need them, in this case you want to perform a function called "transfer weight", it allows you to copy nearest weight info from body to clothes. It is done in weight painting mode and relatively easy, justt go to youtube and search for weight transfer tutorials.

Comment: Thanks a lot you're right but weight transfer still doesn't do 100 % the job so i guess i'll try to dissolve the "hidden" points from the body(shirt) , put the cloak in their places and merge the cloak with the arms , head , shirt and waist ... can you transform your comment to an answer so i can accept it as a solution ?